# Windows user to Webapp - No authentication needed

Tags: windows, login, web-applications

I would like to retrieve the windows user in a webapp.

Currently using Kerberos/Apache/Tomcat, the variable REMOTE_USER is set in http header so is fine.

But now my needs have changed :

- no more client authentication (no more Kerberos)
- user should not have to log into webapp
- need username to check some process from DB or LDAP

I was wondering what would be the cleaner way to pass the information ?

Thank you

Comment: How to get the Windows username from an anonymous connection? I would hope not.

Comment: Is not the topic, but i'm a in a close network, and just rely on windows accounts logging. Once user is logged I don't need to take care of security aspect anymore for this architecture.